# How to easily change between A2DP and HSP/HFP audio profiles by holding a button?

Tags: sound, bluetooth, pulseaudio, microphone, a2dp

I'm aware that PulseAudio doesn't support bidirectional audio in A2DP profile. I use a bluetooth headset and I have to use HSP/HFP profile a lot because I'm always conferencing, but the audio is very bad this way.
I use discord which has a "press to talk" option. It would be very nice if I could just hold a button, and my audio profile would switch to HSP/HFP while that button is pressed, and switch back to A2DP when I released it. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: No, there isn't.